# yii adding font awesome icons in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: yii

I'm trying to add an icon to my bootstrap navbar

this is the icon i'm trying to add `<i class="icon-fa-comments icon-3x "></i>`

i'm currently using this [font awesome extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/fontawesome/) and this [bootstrap extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/)

the icon shows when it's in my html, but not when i add it to nav bar. any idea what i'm missing? sorry still new to Yii, can't find a key other than `label` to do what i want. tried `htmlOptions` but no luck too

```
<?php 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
    'items'=>array(
       //'brand' => CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name), //site name
        //'fixed' => true,
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/contact')),
                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->loginUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Login"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Register"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Profile"), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout").' ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),

            ),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'<i class="icon-fa-comments icon-3x "></i>', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Dropdown', 'url'=>'#', 'items'=>array(
                    array('label'=>'Action', 'url'=>'#'),
                    array('label'=>'Another action', 'url'=>'#'),
                    array('label'=>'Something else here', 'url'=>'#'),
                    '---',
                    array('label'=>'Separated link', 'url'=>'#'),
                )),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
array('icon'=>'icon-fa-comments icon-3x', 'url'=>'#'),
```

Comment: is there any documentation? can't seem to find one.

Comment: unfortunately there are no documentation. When i faced same problem i found this in `TbMenu` source code

Answer (score 2):

In order to display icons in Yii-2 components like Navbar or Nav, you must set encodeLabels to false.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-icons/

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. Just to let others know, you need to set 'encodeLabels'=>false, BEFORE the 'items' array. Setting encodeLabels to false within the individual menu elements does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you get squares on the web page although you have added the css file font-awesome.css successfully. The solution is very easy you and need to place the font directory (containing four font files) as well inside the CSS folder where you have placed font-awesome.css.

The font directory contains four other font files.

fontawesome-webfont.eot

fontawesome-webfont.ttf

fontawesome-webfont.woff

FontAwesome.otf

Answer (score 0):

Jay is right but I found the explanation hard to follow, so I am adding the code here. This is what the working solution looks like:

In the php header (presuming you have installed kartik icons)

```
use kartik\icons\Icon;
Icon::map($this);
...
```

In the nav widget:

```
          echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'encodeLabels' => false, // declaration goes here (before the items)
            'items' => [
                [
                    'label' => Icon::show('home',[
                       'class'=>'your-custom-class-if-needed' 
                    ]),
                    'url' => ['/survey-visits/index'],
                    'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can label encoding for individual element like below:

```
array('label'=>'<i class="icon-fa-comments icon-3x "></i>', 'url'=>'#', 'encode'=>false)
```